# How to retrieve all elements text value present in the screen using selenium?

Tags: selenium

```js
List<String> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
System.out.println("Links count is: "+allLinks.size());
for(WebElement link : allLinks)
System.out.println(link.getText());
```

```html
<span id="Lbl_Code" class="cus-lbl-on">Code</span>

<label for="Chk_OpenCalls">Team Member self assignment of open calls</label>
<font color="red">*</font>
<input type="submit" name="but_save" value="Save" onclick="return teamvalidate();" id="but_save" class="btn cus-btn-save">
```

Please let me know how can i read all elements textvalue from dissimilar tags from the above HTML snippet

Comment: Can you please share HTML code?

Comment: Please find the above html code ,i have to reterive all the label  name from the above Html snippet

Comment: ">Team Member self assignment of open calls" text you want to retrive ?

Comment: Yes i have also  want to retrieve ">Team Member self assignment of open calls"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using XPath:

```
//*[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0]
```

> **text()** Selects all strings
>
> **normalize-space(text())** Selects all strings removing their spaces
>
> **string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0** Selects all texts not empty strings
>
> **//*[CONDICTION]** searching in all document based in a condiction

Comment: Thanks striter Alfa , I used your  code and its worked for me.